# Can't switch sound to HDMI any more in Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I was able to find a solution, when I was writing this question/post, though it was not easy. Since I have already written it, I leave it here as reference.

---

I am not able to make HDMI my sound output. Previously I had switched manually in the sound settings to HDMI sound output, and later I installed the sound switch indicator (2.1.1). It worked last time when I tried, which was a few months ago. Due to the time passed since then, I can not tell what has been changed. I do not know how to debug it.

[image: Alsamixer recognizes the HDMI sound output as card 0]

[image: Volume Control Configuration also sees it]

[image: Volume Control Output Devices can only switch port for the built-in speakers or headphones. No option for HDMI]

The sound switch indicators debug output tells me the following

```
INF # Card[0], port `hdmi-output-1` selected
ERR Failed to map card[0], port `hdmi-output-1` to a stream
```

Getting the possible output names with aplay -L and testing them, I was able to test the sound on the HDMI.

```
speaker-test -D hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=1 -c 2
```

The HDMI sound works, I just do not know how to channel the sound from the browser to the HDMI output.

On the other hand pulse audio does not sees this output:

```
zoltan@aprosag ~ $ pactl list short sinks  
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
```

After restarting alsa with

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Pulseaudio sees the HDMI output both in command line and in the graphical interface:

```
$ pactl list short sinks  
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo-extra1 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
```

After that the indicator switch works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting alsa seemed to resolve the issue.

I am replying to me post, in order to make it appear "solved".